# PHP Strip_tags for div with a specific ID?

Tags: php

Does anybody know if a modified strip_tags function exsists where you can specify the ID of the tags to be stripped, and possbile also specify to remove ALL THE DATA IN THE TAGS. Take for example:

```
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>

Running:


new_strip_tags($data, 'two', true);
```

Must return:

```
<div id="one">
</div>
```

Is there something like this out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not exactly what strip_tags does, it strips the tags but leaves the content. What you want is something like this:

```
function remove_div_with_id($html, $id) {
    return preg_replace('/<div[^>]+id="'.preg_quote($id, '/').'"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/s', '', $html);
}
```

Note that this will not work correctly with nested  tags. If you need that, you might want to use a DOM representation of your HTML.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for that.

```
<?php
$html = '<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
  <div id="one">
    <div id="two">
      bla bla bla
    </div>
  </div>
</body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadhtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$ns = $xpath->query('//div[@id="two"]');
// there can be only one... but anyway
foreach($ns as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $doc->savehtml();
```