# Strip specific spans tags using PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Strip_tags for div with a specific ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392346/php-strip-tags-for-div-with-a-specific-id)

I have a string that contains two types of span tags. One type has an id that starts with the keyword "junk_". The other type, however has some random ids. What I want to do is to use preg_replace to strip out only the "junk_" span tags and their content. I still want to keep the other spans. Here is the string that I have

```
<span id="bla">This is a test</span>. 
<span id="junk_74">Please</span> remove <span id="junk_75">all</span> junk spans.
```

The output I want should look like:

```
<span id="bla">This is a test</span>. remove junk spans.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `id` attribute is not allowed to be all-numeric, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sHtml = preg_replace('/<span[^>]+id="junk_[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/s', '', $sHtml);
```

Also see this [example](http://ideone.com/0qbZz).

Comment: Quit did not work. Does it matter if the junk tag has other attributes besides id?

Comment: It may contain any number of other attributes. In my [example](http://ideone.com/0qbZz) it works. Can you show me the content of the string that doesnt't match?

Comment: Still does not work. Please see my [Example](http://ideone.com/RZR82) here

Comment: Since you've marked my answer as the right one, I suspect that you have now solved the problem. Otherwise, [here](http://ideone.com/5RXYn) is the corrected version of your example. The result string has no longer a `span` with the id `junk`.

Comment: Deeply appreciate your effort. Yes, it was the right answer. You saved my day. Many thanks.